USB fingerprint scanner integration with android kotlin code
I have created an android kotlin app using the jetpack compose,
I want to have an external USB fingerprint scanner integration for getting the image of the fingers from the scanner, then i want to compare them in my kotlin springboot application.
Most of the questions on this platform are old and using the java code, is there any new SDK or integration that I can use to get the image of the user fingerprint in the android app and then compare it in the springboot application.

Contact the manufacturer of the external USB fingerprint scanner and ask them if they offer an SDK for whichever OS platform you wish to use.
